# How to parse JSON in Jmeter using Java or Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I have a problem with JSON parsing in Jmeter.
This is a response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "6138b66a-83df-4860-8327-62f942e0e9b3",
      "artifactory_repo": {
        "maven-snapshot-repo": ""
      },
      "created_by": "system",
      "created_date": "2018-04-17T10:45:55",
      "created_request_id": "",
      "description": "",
      "git_repo": {
        "https://github.com/Leela-Padmaja/example-java-maven.git": ""
      },
      "id": "6138b66a-83df-4860-8327-62f942e0e9b3",
      "jobs": {
        "clone-MavenEx": "http://101.707.106.99:803/job/clone-MavenEx/1/"
      },
      "name": "Test1",
      "pattern": {
        "exclude": [],
        "include": []
      },
      "services": {
        "0727a49a-6c95-433e-9fc5-7e5c760cc76f": {
          "builds": {
            "clone-MavenEx": {
              "last_retrieved": "2018-04-19T11:00:01.011Z"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "updated_by": "system",
      "updated_date": "2018-04-19T11:00:03",
      "updated_request_id": ""
    },
```

I need to get build name for particular **_id** value. For sample above is **clone-MavenEx** without anything else. The _id value I got previously using JSON Extractor.

I used the following Groovy code in JSR223 Post Processor

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult; 
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
String projectID = vars.get("project_id");

def slurper = new JsonSlurper();
def result  = slurper.parseText(jsonString);
def index   = result.find { it._id == projectID };

if ( index == null ) {
    vars.put( "buildName", 'NOTFOUND' );
} else {
    vars.put( "buildName", index.builds.toString() );
}
```

Comment: should be something like this: `result.data.find { it._id == projectID }.services.'0727a49a-6c95-433e-9fc5-7e5c760cc76f'.builds`

Comment: It works, thank you, however I get the following - [clone-MavenEx:[last_retrieved:2018-04-20T10:30:01.015Z]]. I just need clone-MavenEx and anything else

Comment: just add corresponding accessors: `.'clone-MavenEx'.last_retrieved`

Comment: Curious to know why you are not using https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) it is recommended to use JMeter Test Elements and avoid scripting where possible. My expectation is that you can get everything you need using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

The relevant [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) query would be something like:

```
$.data[?(@._id == '6138b66a-83df-4860-8327-62f942e0e9b3')].services[*].builds
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSON Extractor]

If you want you can replace hard-coded project id with the relevant JMeter Variable:

```
$.data[?(@._id == '${project_id}')].services[*].builds
```

Full equivalent configuration:

[image: JMeter JSON Extractor]